# Change upload path (UPLOAD_FOLDER) during the runtime

Tags: python, flask

How to change the upload folder during the runtime? I'd like to be able to change the location where file will be uploaded to, but I don't know how.

I tried something like this, but I get **KeyError**:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    file = request.files['file']
    path = 'uploads/text'
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        UPLOAD_FOLDER = path
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
                                filename=filename))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this

```
file.save(os.path.join(/path/to/save/, filename))
```

In yours

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = path
file.save(os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename))
```

Comment: Uh, it was easy :) Thank you!

Comment: what was the app.config for?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below. It worked perfectly for me.

```
base_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
upload_path = os.path.join(base_path, app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])
f.save(os.path.join(upload_path, secure_filename(f.filename)))
```